# how to transmit user variables to paint method

Tags: java, paint

I'm new to this so there might be many problems in the code below.
It should take user written text from the text field and draw the Morse code for it. It gets the text, transmits the String in CharArray form to this class, but the paint method doesn't draw anything(variables are not recognized in paint method!!).

Input: the constructor gets the link(or what in that)of the other class, a char from the string, and its place number in the string
Output: just the last 3 rows are drawn, other variables from outside paint method are not recognized!

Here is the class that doesn't work:

```
public class Procesare extends Canvas{
    Morse fereastra;
    String lit="",cod="";
    char car;
    int nr;

    public Procesare(Morse parinte,char c,int i){
        fereastra=parinte;
        car=c;  // with or without "this" doesn't seem to transmit values to the class
        nr=i;
        //this.lit=String.valueOf(c);
        switch (c){
                //this part is just testing that values were transmited, it works
                case 'a':
                    fereastra.canv.setBackground(Color.orange);
                    System.out.println(c+" .-");

                    break;
                case 'b': 
                    fereastra.canv.setBackground(Color.blue);
                    System.out.println(c+" -...");

                    break;
                case 'c': 
                    fereastra.canv.setBackground(Color.red);
                    System.out.println(c+" -.-.");

                    break;
                case 'd': 
                    fereastra.canv.setBackground(Color.green); 
                    System.out.println(c+" -..");

                    break;
                default: break;
            }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        lit=String.valueOf(car);
        switch (lit){
                case "a": cod=".-"; break;
                case "b": cod="-..."; break;

                default: break;
            }
        g.drawString(lit,5,10+nr*10);
        g.drawString(cod,15,10+nr*10);
        g.drawString(lit,5,10);  // these aren't drawing anything !?!?

        g.fillOval(15, 3, 6, 6); // just testing
        g.drawString("z",5,20);
        g.fillOval(15, 13, 6, 6); 
    }
}
```

the main class, which works:

```
public class Morse extends Frame {
    xText camp;
    Procesare proc,canv;
    String s1, str;
    char[] cuv;
    int n;

    public Morse(String titlu){
      super(titlu);
      init();
    }  
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Morse app=new Morse("Morse much?");
        app.setSize(250,250);
        app.show();
    }
    public boolean handleEvent(Event evt)  {
      if (evt.id==Event.WINDOW_DESTROY)
      {System.exit(0);}
      return super.handleEvent(evt);
    }

    public void init(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,10,20));
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        canv=new Procesare(this,' ',0);
        canv.setBackground(Color.orange);
        camp=new xText(this,"Introduceti textul aici:");              
        add(camp);
        add(canv);

    }
    public Insets getInsets(){
        return new Insets(30,30,30,30);
    }
    void update(xText input){

        s1=input.cText1.getText();
        cuv = s1.toCharArray();

        for(n=0;n<s1.length();n++){
            proc=new Procesare(this,cuv[n],n);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exceptions that you mentioned in that comment?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: String is null (this is the first line, there are many after, like: at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(SunGraphics2D.java:2817), so on)

Comment: That means the string "lit" and/or "cod" is null when you pass it in.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all of the exceptions, as well as some sample input and it's corresponding output? (actual output, not expected output)

Comment: error resolved: I forgot to give a start value to the 'cod' string, but the paint method still doesn't draw anything that has variables in it